# Unable to access cross rider db data from other browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, plugins, browser, crossrider

I'm working on a new browser extension that will users to store data across browsers. I'm using Cross Rider API for storing this data.

So far, I'm able to store data that persists in same browser using cross rider's appAPI.db. But as i store some data to cross rider database in firefox, i cannot access this data from chrome or IE.

Any solution for this problem would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Crossrider database](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db.async) is an easy to use local storage that provides an extension with its own private browser specific storage. The reason why the same extension installed on different browsers cannot share a single database between them is because each extension runs in a sandbox and is only aware of the environment of the browser it is installed on.

If you want to share data the different browser installation of the extension, you can emulate the behavior by setting up a web-based database server/API and use [appAPI.request](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.request) to send and receive data to/from the remote server.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]